# Python select and count elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Product ID': ['A','B','C','D','A','D','E','A','B','C','B','C','E'], 
'Buyer ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

which is of the format:

```
Product ID  Buyer ID
A             1
B             1
C             1
D             1
A             2
D             2
E             2
A             3
B             3
C             3
B             4
C             5
E             5
```

The dataframe shows the products purchased by an individual over time.

What I would like to do is to obtain the first and last products purchased by an individual and a count of the number of products bought between the first and last purchase. In my example Buyer 1, purchased 4 products in all and his first purchase was Product A and last purchase was product D (Full expected results table provided at the end). In case an individual purchased 1 product only, the resultant count would be 1 with the product listed.

The result I want to obtain is of this format:

```
Product ID  Buyer ID    Count
    A           1         4
    D           1         4
    A           2         3
    E           2         3
    A           3         3
    C           3         3
    B           4         1
    C           5         2
    E           5         2
```

I could not get my head around to solving this. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of functions `["first", "last", "count"]` to aggregate the results and then reshape it to the format you need:

```
(df1.groupby("Buyer ID")["Product ID"].agg(["first", "last", "count"])
 .set_index('count', append=True).stack()
 .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
 .rename("Product ID").reset_index().drop_duplicates())
```

[image]

---

Or another option, use `groupby.apply` and take the first, last row with `iloc`:

```
(df1.groupby("Buyer ID", group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[[0,-1], :].assign(count = len(g)))
 .drop_duplicates())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.